# Portable micro PC computer on USB stick

Tags: usb, micro-pc

I'm looking for portable micro PC (uPC) on a stick (something like Raspberry Pi), but a lot smaller (a USB thumb drive size).

Any architecture is great (ARM is fine), as long as you can install Linux on it (so some storage is a must). Support for Wi-Fi is an advantage.

Here is which I've found so far: [Forget Raspberry PI How About Android on a Stick!](http://www.gizchina.com/2012/03/14/buy-android-raspberry-pi-china/), but the article is a bit out-dated.

Comment: For anyone still interested, the second Intel Compute Stick was just revealed at CES, and is now available to buy. The new version has updated Wifi-802.11ac instead of m, 2 USB ports, and an updated Intel Atom Processor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best answer to your question is the [Intel Compute Stick](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html).

To answer your feature requests:

- It is small-scale being in principle a HMDI stick (~100x27x13mm)
- It has a processor that is good enough ([Atom Z3735F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Atom_microprocessors#.22Bay_Trail-T.22_.2822_nm.29_2))
- It has 8GB (Ubuntu version) or 32GB (Windows version) of memory which is expandable by the MicroSDXC slot
- It has 1GB (ubuntu) or 2GB (windows) RAM
- It has all the usual Wifi standards (802.11b/g/n + Bluetooth 4.0)

If you can wait a few more months / weeks, [a new version was announced at IFA 2015](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2979198/components-processors/intels-pint-sized-compute-stick-pc-powered-up-with-core-m-processor.html).

Answer (score 9):

You might of heard of it, but the [Intel Compute Stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html) is a very small PC running an Intel Atom processor (Atom Z3735F). The standard model has 32GB of flash storage and though it costs $150, it comes with Windows 10, which is nice even if you do plan on installing Linux. You can buy one [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883800004). I actually use this one.

There are two versions of the Intel Compute Stick. The first has Ubuntu preinstalled, 1GB of ram, and 8GB of on board storage. The other has Windows 8.1 installed, 2GB of ram, and 32GB of on board storage.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Firepower and SEJPM that the Intel Compute Stick is the route to go for around $150 but if you are looking for a cheaper version of that, the MeeGoPad T02 is a great alternative for $79 (The Ubuntu Version) and around $109 (The Windows 8.1 with upgrade to Windows 10 Version)

Both sticks have a Intel Atom Z3735f processor, 2GB's of Ram and 32 GB's of flash storage and connect through HDMI. In addition they have 2 full sized USB 2 ports, Wi-Fi B/G/N and Bluetooth 4.0. Finally they have a micro sd slot with support for up to 32 GB's of extra storage

Ubuntu Version: [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011HPKYCK)

Windows Version: [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZFJFOXY)

[image: Image of it]